# Typescript baseUrl with Node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript

To avoid long paths in `import`, I'm using Typescript `baseUrl` option in my `tsconfig.json`

**Here's my `tsconfig.json`:**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",
        "module": "none",
        "removeComments": true,
        "rootDir": "./",
        "outDir": "Build",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "pretty": true,
        "baseUrl": "./"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "Build"
    ]
}
```

**so instead of doing this**

```
import foo from "../../../../hello/foo"
```

**I do this**

```
import foo from "hello/foo"
```

It's working fine in the Typescript compiler, but when I run my app with node.js, I have this error:

```
module.js:474
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'hello/foo'
```

**P.s: I don't want to replace the `require()` function like I've seen on the internet**

So how can I make node.js working with baseUrl or make typescript replacing paths like `"hello/foo"` to `"../../../../hello/foo"` ?

Typescript compiler version:

```
Version 2.3.0-dev.20170303
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Pass `NODE_PATH` env param when you run app with node.js

Example:

```
set NODE_PATH=./src
node server.js
```

Comment: I get this error if I use this: ```Running seed command `NODE_PATH=./ ts-node --compiler-options {"module":"CommonJS"} prisma/seed.ts` ...

An error occured while running the seed command:
Error: Command failed with ENOENT: NODE_PATH=./ ts-node --compiler-options {"module":"CommonJS"} prisma/seed.ts
spawn NODE_PATH=./ ENOENT```

Answer (score 9):

As @jez said you need to set the NODEPATH when running the node app. This is configuration may help you:

tsconfig.json

```
"outDir": "dist",
"baseUrl": "./",
```

Package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "dev": "NODE_PATH=./ ts-node ./src/index.ts",
    "start": "NODE_PATH=./dist node ./dist/index.js",
    "prod": "npm run build && npm run start"
  },
```

Comment: Was this answer intended to work on a Windows 10 OS?  I can't get it to work.  I always get this error from the Nodejs loader: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:15)

Answer (score 2):

Windows users might want to use [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) with above mentioned answers.

package.json

```json
"scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_PATH=./ ts-node ./src/index.ts"
 }
```

Answer (score -3):

Just add this line inside your `tsconfig.json` file.

`"baseUrl": "./src"`

It should work like a charm.

Comment: It does work great for script intended to run in a browser.  But for running on nodejs, the loader doesn't seem to be able to resolve require("abc/xyz"), but it can resolve require("./abc/xyz");