# How to configure Electron to use TypeScript's baseUrl

Tags: typescript, electron

TypeScript has a useful compiler option called `baseUrl` which lets you use non-relative paths, i.e.

`import Command from "util/Command"`

instead of:

`import Command from "../../../util/Command"`

Using it works fine for the compile step, but TypeScript retains the non-relative paths and emits:

`const Command_1 = require("util/Command")`

When running the app with

`$ electron .`

this results in a **Cannot find module 'util/Command'** error, because it doesn't know about the `baseUrl` setting.

I understand this can be solved by using Webpack's `resolve.alias` but I'm not using Webpack in this project and don't want to add it in just for this.

I already tried the suggestions below but neither of them worked:

- Set `NODE_PATH` env variable
  ([Typescript baseUrl with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42582807/typescript-baseurl-with-node-js))
- Add to `require('module').globalPaths`
  [Issue #11](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/11)
- Use TSPath library, plain broken: 
  [Issue #1](https://github.com/duffman/tspath/issues/1)

Answer (score 0):

TSPath works fine for this, the issue you are relating to did force you to keep a specific directory structure, which was a miss, however it´s been used for commercial products for over 10 months, so I wouldn´t call it plain broken, I suspect something else is plain broken on your end project wise or...

The bug you are referring to: https://github.com/duffman/tspath/issues/1 have been fixed, you can now place your dist dir wherever you want, but as said, since you ended up here...

Follow the steps in the readme