# How to run Prisma seed file in NextJS

Tags: node.js, next.js, prisma

Prisma normally allows you to run a seed.ts file on your NextJS project to populate your DB with data after you run `npx prisma migrate dev`.

To do this this, you write your seed.ts file and then add the following to your package.json:

seed.ts:

```
import logger from "../utils/pino-logger";
import { BytesLike, ethers } from "ethers";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
const prisma = new PrismaClient();

async function main() {
  const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY! as BytesLike);
  const nonce = await prisma.wallet.create({
    data: {
      nonce: await wallet.getTransactionCount("pending"),
    },
  });

  logger.debug({ nonce: nonce });
}

main()
  .then(async () => {
    await prisma.$disconnect();
  })
  .catch(async (e) => {
    console.error(e);
    await prisma.$disconnect();
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

package.json

```
"prisma": {
  "seed": "ts-node prisma/seed.ts"
},
```

I have tried this option, but it gives me the following error:

```
import logger from "utils/pino-logger";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1032:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1067:27)
    at Module.m._compile (/Users/dimitriborgers/Documents/3mint/3mint-core/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1618:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/Users/dimitriborgers/Documents/3mint/3mint-core/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1621:12)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at phase4 (/Users/dimitriborgers/Documents/3mint/3mint-core/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:649:14)
```

Prisma recommends using `ts-node --compiler-options {\"module\":\"CommonJS\"} prisma/seed.ts` if you're having an issue. But, if I do this, I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'utils/pino-logger'
Require stack:
- /Users/dimitriborgers/Documents/3mint/3mint-core/prisma/seed.ts
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename.sharedData.moduleResolveFilenameHook.installedValue [as _resolveFilename] (/Users/dimitriborgers/Documents/3mint/3mint-core/node_modules/@cspotcode/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:811:30)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/dimitriborgers/Documents/3mint/3mint-core/prisma/seed.ts:1:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Module.m._compile (/Users/dimitriborgers/Documents/3mint/3mint-core/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1618:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/Users/dimitriborgers/Documents/3mint/3mint-core/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1621:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/Users/dimitriborgers/Documents/3mint/3mint-core/prisma/seed.ts' ]
}
```

I'm using ts.config to put a base url of `"baseUrl": "."`. However, even if I change that and fix the error for pino-logger, the issue pops up for ethers, which is a library I don't really control (and would rather not do an absolute path to a node module).

```
Running seed command `ts-node --compiler-options {"module":"CommonJS"} prisma/seed.ts` ...
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toHexString')
    at isHexable (/Users/dimitriborgers/Documents/3mint/3mint-core/node_modules/@ethersproject/bytes/src.ts/index.ts:58:21)
    at hexlify (/Users/dimitriborgers/Documents/3mint/3mint-core/node_modules/@ethersproject/bytes/src.ts/index.ts:228:9)
    at new SigningKey (/Users/dimitriborgers/Documents/3mint/3mint-core/node_modules/@ethersproject/signing-key/src.ts/index.ts:35:51)
    at new Wallet (/Users/dimitriborgers/Documents/3mint/3mint-core/node_modules/@ethersproject/wallet/src.ts/index.ts:87:36)
    at /Users/dimitriborgers/Documents/3mint/3mint-core/prisma/seed.ts:7:18
    at step (/Users/dimitriborgers/Documents/3mint/3mint-core/prisma/seed.ts:33:23)
    at Object.next (/Users/dimitriborgers/Documents/3mint/3mint-core/prisma/seed.ts:14:53)
    at /Users/dimitriborgers/Documents/3mint/3mint-core/prisma/seed.ts:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/Users/dimitriborgers/Documents/3mint/3mint-core/prisma/seed.ts:4:12)
```

Any way to fix this??

Comment: Your project using `javascript` or `typescript` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few things going on here. I'll try to explain why your earlier attempts had issues below, but your last attempt with `ts-node --compiler-options {"module":"CommonJS"} prisma/seed.ts` is the closest. The error you are receiving sounds like `process.env.PRIVATE_KEY` is not set. Try logging that value or hardcoding it to verify. If you're using a `.env` file, you'll probably need to call `dotenv` manually at the start of the file or register it on the CLI. The [dotenv README](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#usage) has some usage examples.

For your first attempt with `ts-node prisma/seed.ts`, the error `Cannot use import statement outside a module` indicates that Node is running in CommonJS mode, but the code it's trying to run uses the modern module syntax with `import` or `export`. When you added `--compiler-options {\"module\":\"CommonJS\"}`, TypeScript started converting the `import` to `require` instead. See the [TypeScript module docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module) for more info on that.

For the next issue, you noted that you had `"baseUrl": "."` for the `utils/pino-logger` import and it still couldn't find it. That's because the `tsconfig.json` file only tells TypeScript to allow imports relative to the root directory, but TypeScript doesn't rewrite the module paths or influence Node's resolution strategy. For more details on that see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9259) or [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42582807/typescript-baseurl-with-node-js).

I hope that's helpful!

Comment: Incredibly helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was not aware of this option. so I wrote an api function inside `pages/api/seed.ts` directory and visited `api/seed` route on the browser and it run the code. for example,

```
export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<Data>
) {

async function main() {
  const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY! as BytesLike);
  const nonce = await prisma.wallet.create({
    data: {
      nonce: await wallet.getTransactionCount("pending"),
    },
  });

  logger.debug({ nonce: nonce });
}    
 await main()    
 res.status(200).json({ message: "successfully seeded" });    
}
```